# ERRNO 36 File name too long

Tags: python, string

I am working on a python coding project to censor certain words from a txt file.  Most of the solutions have involved opening the txt file and storing it in a variable, then iterating through the string.  I keep finding these results to be inconsistent so I am attempting a different method.

Example Code:

```
def strip_by_list(email, list):
    with open(email, 'r') as file:
        filedata = file.read()
        for term in list:
            filedata.replace(term, "**REDACTED**")

    return filedata
```

I am attempting to define a function that allows input of the file, and a list of words to check for potential redaction.

Intended Code Function

1. Open Selected Email as file
2. take that data and store it in a variable filedata
3. iterate through the terms in list
4. for each instance of that word, replace it with **REDACTED**
5. return the variable filedata

I keep drawing the following error, i have *** all the directories

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home********", line 45, in <module>
    print(strip_by_list(email_two, proprietary_terms))
  File "/home/********************", line 38, in strip_by_list
    with open(email, 'r') as file:
OSError: [Errno 36] File name too long
```

Any input would be appreciated.

1st update:

As suggested, I changed the code to store the information back into a variable:

```
def strip_by_list(email, list):
    with open(email, 'r') as file:
        for term in list:
            file = file.replace(term, "**REDACTED**")

return file
```

--This did not resolve the error.  It it is still trying to list the entire contents of the message in the file name--

to answer the other questions

1. Ubunutu linux filesystem
2. the file path is very long because of the amount of sub directories
3. the file has been successfully opened and used in another area of code.

eg:

```
email_one = open("email_one.txt", "r").read()
```

Then used here:

```
def censor(terms, email):
    new_message = email.replace(terms, "*REDACTED*")
    return new_message
```

Comment: How long is the filename when it errors?  Some encrypted filesystems can shorten the maximum to like 143 characters, while the OS usually is much higher.

Comment: Unrelated problem: `filedata.replace()` doesn't update `filedata` in place. You need to assign the result: `filedata = filedata.replace(term, "**REDACTED**")`

Comment: The problem is probably in the caller, it's generating the filename improperly.

Comment: This seems like a file system issue, as mentioned in other comments. Please better describe the path length and nature of the FS. Also, how is the file saved to begin with and if you succeed with the open in another code part.

Comment: @Jimmy Smith, it is long and because of the amount of subdirectories, I had considered this. but I think Barmar might have identified the solution.  I am going to try his result.

Comment: @amotzg this is on standard ubuntu LTS.

Comment: @amotzg I am able to open the txt file and save it to a variable and use it in another area.  I created a separate python file and loaded the variables "" email_one = open("email_one.txt", "r").read()
email_two = open("email_two.txt", "r").read()

Comment: I specifically said that fixing the call to `replace()` was **unrelated** to the error. Why did you think it would resolve the error?

Comment: `file.replace()` makes no sense. `file` is not a string, it doesn't have a `replace()` method. That version of the function is never reading from the file.

Comment: Add a `try/except` block that catches the error and prints the filename. Make sure `email` is what you really expected.

Comment: 'It it is still trying to list the entire contents of the message in the file name'. what do you mean by this? what is the argument `email`?

Comment: @NullAntechamber as noted by Barmar and L. Grozinger, it seems to be a problem with what you get in the `email` argument. Is it really the file path? I see the `censor` method receive a parameter with the same name, and have it second in method signature, this might be confusing. Try using the signature `strip_by_list(terms_list, email_file_path)`.